# How to measure the execution time of the ruby code inside API controller's action when query is calling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is an api query that response takes 6 seconds. I am looking in Datadog, and that looks like all SQL queries take an exec time of 2 seconds. What the rest of the time is not clear. Maybe do you know some gems or tools how can I measure the execution time?  Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html)

```
require 'benchmark'

puts Benchmark.measure { #code_you_want_to_measure }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler).

> Features
>
> - Database profiling - Currently supports Mysql2, Postgres, Oracle
>   (oracle_enhanced ~> 1.5.0) and Mongoid3 (with fallback support to
>   ActiveRecord)
> - Call-stack profiling - Flame graphs showing time spent
>   by gem
> - Memory profiling - Per-request memory usage, GC stats, and
>   global allocation metrics